# How to write multiline if-shell in tmux

Tags: tmux

I'm getting an error in the last line of this code and I don't know exactly what it is but it's probably got to do with the quotes. I want to know what quotes do I have to use if I'm gonna nest ones inside of another. Could I write the outer and inner quotes both with double quotes, or do I have to alternate them or what?

```
if-shell "uname | grep -q Darwin" ' \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'; \
    bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"; \
    bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste-buffer"' ' \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -selection clipboard -in"'
```

Edit: it's working now. Or at least the Linux or else part works. I haven't tested the Mac or true part. I need to know why it works like this and not like before:

```
if-shell "uname | grep -q Darwin" " \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'; \
    bind C-c run 'tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'; \
    bind C-v run 'tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste-buffer'" " \
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -selection clipboard -in'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do, for instance:

```
if-shell true { cmd1; cmd2 }
```

or

```
if-shell true {
cmd;cmd;
}
```

It is explained in the man page.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is `if-shell condition { true-cmd } { false-cmd }`. Is that the way you would do it?

Comment: @Arturo I don't see the `else` part in your question. you can write two `if-shell` for that right?

Comment: The else part isn't in the question but it is in the code example I've copied. The last line would be the else, and the previous 3 the true part. But I don't really mind about the else what I want to know is how to write a multiline if, the one you show isn't actually multiline as all the commands are on the same line. And the difficulty I'm having in the multiline is with the quotes. I didn't know I could write it with braces, it is much easier like that. If you write my example code in your way I'll accept the answer even though it doesn't resolve my quotes doubt.